# Get HTML snippets/suggestions when in ERB mode (VSCode)

Tags: visual-studio-code

When in ERB language mode, I'd like to have all the html and emmett shortcuts/snippets available. I usually switch back and forth between HTML and ERB mode depending on what kinds of tags I need at the moment, but that's a pain, and I also like to always have the ERB code colors. IS there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Have the same problem with PHP

Comment: I don't know anything about ERB but can you try the setting:"emmet.includeLanguages": {
  "ruby": "html"
} or something similar for the emmet functionality.  Another possibility is to associate the ERB files to html ala: "files.associations": { "*.ERB" :  "html" }

Comment: @Mark that is exactly right! Want to reply that as an answer so I can mark it as THE answer?

Comment: Which suggestion worked? The emmet one or the files.associations or both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know anything about `ERB` but can you try the setting:

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": { "ruby": "html" }
```

or something similar for the emmet functionality.

Another possibility is to associate the ERB files to html ala:

```
"files.associations": { "*.ERB" : "html" }
```

Comment: Thanks Mark! I used the first one. I had already thought about using that second one, but I didn't want erb files to show up as HTML files since then I wouldn't get the erb coloring or the erb snippets (like for `each` and `link_to` etc)

Comment: I used the second one, it works. But it only is changing a extention.

Answer (score 7):

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": { "ruby": "html" }
```

It doens't work

But if it changes "ruby" to "erb", works fine.

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": { "erb": "html" }
```

In mac, type `cmd + shift + p`, open settings json. and add upper option or change it.